# Modal popup disappearing after button click causing postback in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I want to show a modal popup after button click that causes postback.
I have the following code:

```
Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
ScriptManager.RegisterPostBackControl(mybutton);
}

mybutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
// some code that needs postback

// after postback I want to show modal popup

var script = "$('#modalName').modal('show');";
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "ModalScript", script, true);
}
```

The popup is not showing, how to overcome this issue?

Comment: Try replacing `RegisterClientScriptBlock` to `RegisterStartupScript`.

Comment: @SuprabhatBiswal Thanks! it worked!